# Changing ascx file and avoiding compilation error

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a user control and making some changes to the HTML. When I do so and refresh the page, I get a compilation error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ASP.usercontrols_somepagename_ascx' exists in both 'c:\Users\compname\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\dev\342db40c\e48a4253\App_Web_1hgtod1r.dll' and 'c:\Users\compname\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\dev\342db40c\e48a4253\App_Web_nqhev1ea.dll'

So everytime I make a change, I need to rebuild the site. This works but it's a pain. How can I remove this extra step and fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: No, normally you can change an ASCX file without needing to rebuild, or even stop the debugger. I don't think you've provided enough information to analyze the errors any deeper.

Comment: Are you changing the user control while your website is running?

Comment: @H.Aghassi: I press play to launch the website the first time around and then I press stop. I make those changes after I press the stop command.

Comment: @JonathanWood: well actually, it works fine about 10% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a path similar to the following:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

or

```
c:\Users\compname\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\dev
```

Delete the contents of this entire folder (no harm will be done), then try and Clean and Rebuild your solution.